# Creating a base class for customizing the view and let other (UIViews) inherit from that class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I read this post but I can't get it working: [Change Background Color...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017616/change-the-background-color-of-all-the-viewcontrollers-iphone)

I like to create a base `UIView` class for all my view customization like background pattern, color of the buttons, color of the tab bar etc.

This is what I've tried:

- Created a new `Single View Application`
- Customized the view in `UIViewController` method `-viewDidLoad`
- Created a new subclass of that `UIViewController`
- In IB I created a new `UIViewController` object
- In IB (Identity Insp.) I set the `UIViewController` class to the subclass I created earlier

Is this not the proper way to do this?
I was thinking that the new created `UIViewController` class will inherit all
customizations from my first `UIViewController` class since I subclassed that one.

Second question is how can I use a base class for certain objects instead of a whole view?
For example how do I let all `UIButtons` in my App inherit all the behavior I have defined in just one single class?

Hope you can help.

Happy Easter for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to customize your view, but exactly how and when is not clear to me.. so I will just give the common method which will give you the general idea of how to do it..

First create a subclass of `UIView` say `BaseView` with properties to be customized, now in the viewDidLoad methods of your viewController create an object of `BaseView` and customize this object as you like.. once this is done just set the self.view property of your viewController to this newly created `BaseView` object and then release the `BaseView` object.. 
hoping this helps you somewhat...

EDIT:
based on the comments ..
First create a `BaseViewController` class which subclasses `UIViewController`... in the `viewDidLoad` of this class customize your view using `self.view`

Second now the viewControllers which you want to use in your `tabController` should subclass this `BaseViewController`... just don't forget the `[super viewDidLoad];` is called in the `viewDidLoad` of this viewcontroller.

this is the best I have to offer.. :) let me know if it works for you.

Comment: To keep it simple. You have a Tabbed Application with two tab bar items each with a UIVIewController class (Basic Xcode Tabbed Application Template). Instead of saying in each -viewDidLoad method in all two UIVIewController classes that background color should be green I like an own class telling all the views to have a green background color.

Comment: you want to change this dynamically or will this be a one time thing...?

Comment: Example: I have a single view application with a UIViewController class. To get a green background color on that view I say: [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9828/discussion-between-marc-and-ankit-srivastava)